# Include JQuery and JQuery UI in Wordpress header.php

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui

Ive tried a lot of versions of doing this I have found on SO and the net but none have worked for me.

I am running version 3.4.2. Perhaps there is a different way of doing it for this version?

My code is:

```
<?php
function my_scripts_method() {
  wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery', '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js' );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.8/jquery-ui.min.js' );

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method' );
?>
```

I have this just above the `</head>` tag.

Can anyone help me out and tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: you can always include it directly without these wrapper functions

Comment: @DevZer0 Thanks - I did try that too. No luck

Comment: then your placing it in the wrong header file, make sure the header file you choose is for the one of the current theme.

Comment: Try putting it inside functions.php in the current theme directory.

Answer (score 1):

Had similiar issue and I fixed it first deregister, register it to your value and than enqueue

At http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script

> If you try to register or enqueue an already registered handle with
>   different parameters, the new parameters will be ignored. Instead, use
>   wp_deregister_script() and register the script again with the new
>   parameters.

```
wp_deregister_script('jquery');
wp_register_script('jquery', '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js');
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

wp_deregister_script('jquery');
wp_register_script('jquery-ui', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.8/jquery-ui.min.js');
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
```